# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring 4.0.5, Hibernate 4.3.5 and JSF for web developpement in eclipse, and this is the content of my `lib` folder :

[image]

When I run my project I get this error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EMaEval]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EMaEval]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more
```

these are the configuration files :

`web.xml`

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name></display-name>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

`application-context.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/ schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value ="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="toor"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://172.16.83.128:5432/emaeval" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.models" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hiberante.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="tansactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

How can I solve this probelm ?

Comment: check if you have exported all the JARs

Comment: As a side note: Maybe you should think about using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: @TheLostMind do you mean did I improted all Spring's jars ?

Comment: you are showing your `eclipse` view, just check your `lib` folder in the final `war` file and look for `spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure, following jar file included in your class path and lib folder.

***spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar***

[image]

if you are using maven, make sure you have included dependency for spring-core-3xxxxx.jar file

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
 <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Note : Replace ${org.springframework.version} with version number.

Comment: I have Spring-core-5.0.8 in my Spring 5 project already, yet receiving this error

Comment: Cannot help. Still, getting trouble with spring in Atlassian plugins

Answer (score 9):

`org.springframework.core.io.Resource` is part of `spring-core-<version>.jar`

But this lib is already in your lib folder. So I guess it is just a Deployment Problem. -- Try to clean your server and redeploy your application.

Comment: Worked for me, I used clean and clean tomcat work directory of eclipse to redeploy my application. I didn't get the reason for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Right-Click on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly.

On the Left-hand panel Click 'Add' and add the '**Project and External Dependencies**'.

'**Project and External Dependencies**' will have all the spring related jars deployed along with your application

Answer (score 1):

There is a version conflict between jar/dependency please check all version of spring is same.
if you use maven remove version of dependency and use Spring.io dependency.it handle version conflict. Add this in your pom

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar files on class path NOT modulepath.

[Eclipse Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNJQV.png)

Comment: Thanks this really helped, i was adding JAR files in modulepath due to which error was showing.

Answer (score 0):

I received same error despite jar being in lib directory & added to deployment assembly in Eclipse.

So I doubted two things ,

1.Some Weblogic cache issue - as this app was deployed before & I was trying to redeploy after some changes

2.Jar itself is corrupt due to partial download etc

So I re downloaded the jar & deleted everything in directory - **..\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib**  and redeployed again & all went well.