# Error when open file ireport

Tags: java, spring, jar, jasper-reports, ireport

I try to open file jrxml in iReport-3.7.2 but throw this error. I search for google but i can't find solution.

I have iReport-3.7.2 because the program use is old and now I change a little bit the program.

```
Error loading the report template.
Message:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
Level:
    SEVERE
Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:102)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:505)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:198)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:175)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:135)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:121)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:98)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.findComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:90)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getCachedComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:78)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:66)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:157)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.configureParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:138)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.createParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:103)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1332)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1307)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:205)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:87)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:505)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:198)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:175)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:135)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:121)
    net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:98)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.findComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:90)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getCachedComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:78)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:66)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:157)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.configureParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:138)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.createParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:103)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1332)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1307)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:205)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:87)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:505)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="GETIOFE" pageWidth="98" pageHeight="100" columnWidth="98" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="2" bottomMargin="2">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="5.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <style name="style1" isDefault="false" markup="styled">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[!$P{PVG2}.equals("0.00")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style isDefault="false" style="style1" mode="Opaque" markup="styled" fontName="Impact" fontSize="14" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="style2" isDefault="false" markup="styled">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[!$P{PVG1}.equals("0.00")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style isDefault="false" style="style2" mode="Opaque" markup="styled" fontName="Arial" fontSize="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="REFERENCIA" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["157157"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DESCRIPCION" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["ANGEL EP ETOILE  25 VAP      F"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="PVG1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PVG2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TXTPEU" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PVG3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TXTIDIOMA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TXTIDOFER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 AS PP]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PP" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="DTO" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Double(
((Double.parseDouble($P{PVG1}.replace(",",".")) -
Double.parseDouble($P{PVG2}.replace(",",".")))/
Double.parseDouble($P{PVG1}.replace(",",".")))*100
)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="51" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" style="style1" mode="Opaque" x="50" y="14" width="43" height="27" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Impact" size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{PVG2} + "<style size=\"9\">€</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="50" y="42" width="43" height="7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="5" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TXTPEU}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-3" x="2" y="42" width="93" height="1" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-2" x="78" y="6" width="17" height="7">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{TXTIDOFER}.equals("")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="5" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TXTIDOFER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-3" x="3" y="43" width="47" height="8"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REFERENCIA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="style2" x="3" y="14" width="47" height="9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["PVP : " + $P{PVG1} + "<style size=\"5\">€</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-3" x="2" y="13" width="93" height="1" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="3" y="0" width="89" height="7" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" lineSpacing="Single" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[( $P{DESCRIPCION}.length()<=22 ? $P{DESCRIPCION}.substring(0,$P{DESCRIPCION}.length()) : $P{DESCRIPCION}.substring(0,22) )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-3" x="3" y="6" width="75" height="7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[( $P{DESCRIPCION}.length()<=22 ? "." : $P{DESCRIPCION}.substring(22,$P{DESCRIPCION}.length()) )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement style="style2" mode="Transparent" x="3" y="32" width="47" height="9" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" lineSpacing="Single" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TXTIDIOMA}.equals("CAT") ?
"DTE€: -" + $P{PVG3} + "<style size=\"5\">€</style>"
:
"DTO€: -" + $P{PVG3} + "<style size=\"5\">€</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement style="style2" mode="Transparent" x="3" y="23" width="47" height="9" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" lineSpacing="Single" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TXTIDIOMA}.equals("CAT") ?
"DTE%: -" + new Integer($V{DTO}.intValue()) + "<style size=\"5\"> %</style>"
:
"DTO%: -" + new Integer($V{DTO}.intValue()) + "<style size=\"5\"> %</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: List of dependencies? `pom.xml`, `build.gradle` or whatever?

Comment: have a look on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259508/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-io-resource