# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePropertiesPersister

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I upgrade spring framework version form 5.2.x to 5.3.x and get eror when running tests

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePropertiesPersister
```

How fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259508/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-io-resource)

Comment: If you get that you are mixing jars from differnt versions of Spring. Post your build file.

Comment: @M.Deinum if uprade spring-ws-core from 2.4.0 to 3.1.1 and need upgrade Spring Security (use guide https://spring.io/blog/2021/05/20/spring-web-services-3-1-1-is-out) build UNIT test is complete.

Comment: Need to check the launch of applications on the server

Comment: @ShriHariL no, i saw this question